# IndexError: Constraint 'restr1': Cannot initialize multiple indices of a constraint with a single expression

Tags: python-3.x, constraints, pyomo

Please I need helping hands to resolve the above error I posted as my title. I am new to pyomo. I was recently following this link: 
    https://github.com/amianAA/ALNS. In the MadridALNS.py, everything works perfectly up to the where the constraints are created:

```
#2 // arrival flow to each destination "wd" equal to demand of the destination origin pair "w"

    def resd1_rule(model,w):
        wo=model.tabla[w,'wo']
        expr=0
        for l in model.L:
            if model.b[wo,l]==1:
                expr += model.fo[w,l]
        if expr!=0:
                return (expr + model.h[w]==model.tabla[w,'g']*model.factorg)
        else:
                return Constraint.Skip
    model.restr1 = Constraint(model.W,expr=resd1_rule)
```

This is the error i get whenever i run the code:

```
ERROR: Constructing component 'restr1' from data=None failed:
    IndexError: Constraint 'restr1': Cannot initialize multiple indices of
    a constraint with a single expression
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "ALNS.py", line 16, in <module>
   instance = model.create_instance('madridALNS.dat')
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyomo/core/base/PyomoModel.py", line 723, in create_instance
   profile_memory=profile_memory )
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyomo/core/base/PyomoModel.py", line 806, in load
   profile_memory=profile_memory)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyomo/core/base/PyomoModel.py", line 870, in _load_model_data
   self._initialize_component(modeldata, namespaces, component_name, profile_memory)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyomo/core/base/PyomoModel.py", line 925, in _initialize_component
  declaration.construct(data)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyomo/core/base/constraint.py", line 786, in construct
   (self.name,) )
  IndexError: Constraint 'restr1': Cannot initialize multiple indices of a constraint with a single expression
```

The files can be found here https://github.com/amianAA/ALNS

Answer (score 0):

The `expr=` argument is intended for a single non-indexed expression. You should try `rule=resid1_rule` instead.

Comment: I'm honored for your reply. When I used 'rule=resid1_rule' instead, I immediately run into the following error message: 'ValueError: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object fo[1,1_C1]'. I dont understand why i got that error. Thanks in advance

Comment: You're getting into a different question here, but it means that for some reason the program is trying to access `value(fo[1,1_C1])` when its value is `None`. I would have to see the stack trace to say more.

Comment: I'm getting closer to understanding the error per your reply but my problem is how to fix it. I will edit the question by adding the stack trace of this second error, so you can have a look at it. Thank you once more for your reply!

Comment: You can simply open up a new StackOverflow question as well. I don't think that `Answer Your Question` is intended for that use.

Comment: I have just opened a new StackOverflow question. You can have a look at it. Thanks in Advance